# Find highest voted in each country

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app with Users and Countries models.  User has an attribute votes_count and belongs to a country.  I am trying to write the rails query that would find the user in each country with the highest vote count.  something like

```
User.order(:votes_count).joins(:country).group_by(:country_id)
```

I know this isn't correct syntax just an example of what I need.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a try with this `User.includes(:country).select('MAX(votes_count').group_by(:country_id)`

Comment: @Pavan I believe your solution would only fetch the MAX(votes_count) as result. Not the required user data matching the condition.

Answer (score 1):

if I understood correctly you have the User model that belongs to a Country, and the User model has a column named 'votes_count'.

In this case you do not have to specify the join in the rails query but for example if you want to check the user with higher votes in australia you just need to select the country your are checking  :

```
australia = Country.find_by_name 'australia' # I'm assuming Country has a name column
```

then order the user by votes_cont and take the first one :

```
first_australian = australia.users.order('votes_cont DESC').first
```

let me know if helps
if I do not understood correctly your models can you specify better their associations?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
User.joins(:country).group(:country_id).having("MAX(votes_count)")
```

I dont know your schema. But something like this should possibly work.